# select first and last row which have the same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

i have an sql table, which has 3 columns (ID, Name, Datetime).

Here is an short Example:

```
ID  |     Name    |        Datetime         |
=============================================
1   |  Test 1     |   2014-09-22 22:27:24   |
2   |  Test 223   |   2014-09-22 22:27:24   |
3   |  Test FAS   |   2014-09-22 22:27:24   |
4   |  Test SSA   |   2014-09-22 22:31:18   |
5   |  Test SSA   |   2014-09-22 22:31:18   |
6   |  Test SSA   |   2014-09-22 22:31:18   |
7   |  Test SSA   |   2014-09-22 22:31:18   |
8   |  Test SSA   |   2014-09-22 22:31:18   |
```

For all Entry's which have the same Datetime, I need the first ID (where this datetime starts) and also the last ID (where this datetime is used the last time).

I'm trying to find the right SQL Command to get this result and generate an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1
            [end] => 3
            [date] => 2014-09-22 22:27:24
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 4
            [end] => 8
            [date] => 2014-09-22 22:31:18
        )
```

Could someone give me a solution, how to create this sql command?

Thanks!

Comment: You say "First" to you mean the Min(ID). Same with "Last", do you mean Max(ID)?

Comment: Okay, i didn't know that it is called min and max ID, but yes for all entry's that have the same datetime i need min and max then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
MIN(ID) AS start,
MAX(ID) AS end,
COUNT(*) AS how_many,
`Datetime`
FROM
your_table
GROUP BY `Datetime`
```

Comment: That looks really good and works great :) Is it easy to add a count? so that I know how many entrys?

Comment: Thanks Mr. fancyPants :)